# How to disable in-app purchases in appcelerator - they are preventing me from creating a provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, appcelerator

I am trying to get a provisioning profile created for my appcelerator app in order to test on a physical iphone but unfortunately, even when following the appropriate steps to make a provisioning profile (going to `xcode`, opening the `general` tab, and then clicking `fix issue` and setting my user profile), xcode gives an error saying that `The 'In-App Purchase' feature is only available to users enrolled in Apple Developer Program. Please visit 
https://developer.apple.com/programs/ to enroll.`

I am not using any in app purchase feature within appcelerator so I can't see why appcelerator would be trying to turn in app purchases on. What files would I have to change to manually disable them such that I can make the provisioning profile? Thanks!

**Note:** I can't just go to the `capabilities` tab and turn them off because the UI says `8 Capabilities Unavailable` and won't provide for any way to turn in-app purchases off.

Comment: Are you not enrolled in Apple Developer Program, if not then how are you creating the provisioning profile (PP)?

Comment: Since Xcode 7, you can build onto devices without needing enrollment in the Apple Developer Program. I don't have access to the code I was working on now, so I can't test any suggestions.

Comment: Yes, we can now but it seems that there should not be any accounts logged in previously in Xcode. Or better search where to find In-App Purchase option in Xcode and see if there is an option to disable it.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?

Comment: I did not get an answer to this and it's honestly been so long since I worked on this that I don't even remember what I did to resolve/work around this. Sorry I can't be any more help.